# Nest a link within a class with SASS

Tags: sass

How can I nest the following in SASS?

```
.class {
  // First styles
}

a.class:visited {
  // Second styles
}
```

I can nest the :visited pseudo class with this, but im not sure how to add the link element?

```
.class {
  // First styles

  &:visited {
    // Second styles
  }
}
```

Comment: Well how do you *think* you would do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don’t know why you’d want that, adding the `a` probably just adds unnecesary specificity. If you really need that there’s probably a design flaw somewhere else.

That said, you can make it work using interpolation around the `&`. However that doesn’t really give you the expected result so you need `@at-root` as well to make it work.

```
.class {
  // some styles...

  @at-root a#{&}:visited {
    // ...more styles!
  }
}
```

I don’t think this is the best way of solving your problem though. Using Sass should result in easier maintainable code.